# php mysql_select_db not selecting

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having problems selecting the DB I would like to use. I can connect to the DB but when I am trying to select the database I want its getting an error. As far as I can tell I'm doing it right.

php code

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '**********', '***********');
if (!$connection) {
    die("DB Connection Faild" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('web_clients', $connection);
if (!$select_db) {
    die("DB select Faild" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

Here's my PHPmyAdmin

[image]

If anyone knows what I can do let me know I'm new to this :)

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* anymore . Use PDO or mysqli_* functions. Don't confuse in both.

Comment: `mysql_connect` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Use mysqli_connect with DB Name : 

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

Comment: you are using ```mysql_connect()``` but for fetching error u r using ```mysqli_error()```. You need to use ```mysql_error()```. But the way "Ravi" has said don't use ```mysql``` extension. That's already deprecated. Rather use PHP PDO or MySQLi extension .

Comment: Does the user you're connecting with have access to that database? You're mixing APIs here, so you don't get a proper error message. Fix that too

Comment: @JayGosai Gosai so your saying I don't need to have an mysqli_select_db I can do it all in one go with ($connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', '******', '********', 'web_clients');) and that will connect to the DB and select that DB name ?

Comment: @RyanJ You can do it both way. If you want to select the DB with connection then use $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db"); & if you want to select db separately then you can use mysqli_select_db($con,"test");

Comment: @JayGosai I have tried doing it all with mysqli_connect('localhost', '*******', '*******', 'web_clients') but it's still not working could it be something to do with my DB name? And I'm presuming I have got the right DB name?

Comment: @RyanJ can you please post the error you are getting ??

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is deprecated in PHP5 and completely removed in PHP7 use mysqli (mysql improved) instead !

```
    <?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', '****', '****');
    if (!$connection) {
        die("DB Connection Faild" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'yourdbname'); // connection must be first
    if (!$select_db) {
        die("DB select Faild" . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
```

here is a clean way to connect with mysqli :

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform a query, check for error
if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')"))
  {
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: If you recommend switching to mysqli, remember that it has `mysqli_connect_error()` for checking the connection. Also, you can specify the database as the 4th argument to `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm still getting the same error even when I make them mysqli. It's making the connection just can't seem to select the DB and I think I'm using the right DB name?

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'primary_website', 'Jobson2171!');
if (!$connection) {
 die("DB Connection Faild" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db('web_clients', $connection);
if (!$select_db) {
 die("DB select Faild" . mysqli_error($connection));
}

Comment: just add the 4th parameter on `mysqli_connect()`no need to add `mysqli_select_db()`

Comment: @ForDev When I add the 4th parameter It can't make the connection I think I have the name of the DB right $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', '******', '*********', 'web_clients'); Is that right ?

Comment: @ForDev Well it's hitting my DB Connection Failed error from the IF so I would think its something to do with the DB name not being right or that it's not going the right permissions but I'm really new to this so don't really know where to start. And I'm presuming I have got the right DB name?

Comment: @RyanJ follow this and im sure u will get the point https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp follow the Procedural way since you are new and make sure the db name is set correctly on your mysql